# Spring - inject contents of file from classpath into annotated member

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations, java-io

Is it possible to inject the contents of a file on classpath to a member variable upon construction of the corresponding class?

```
@Component
public class MyClass {
    @Value("classpath:my_file.txt")
    private String myFile;
}
```

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639209/spring-expression-read-file-content

Answer (score 2):

There is the annotation @Value, but it will inject a Resource, not its contents.

But once you have the resource, you can easily read its contents with class [StreamUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StreamUtils.html) as below:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.util.StreamUtils;

@Value("classpath:/file.txt")
public void setFile(Resource myRes) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream is = myRes.getInputStream()) {
        // Content of the file as a String
        String contents = StreamUtils.copyToString(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure

```
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

@Value("classpath:my_file.txt")
private Resource myFile;
```

Comment: Resource is not a String!